# Does anyone know how to import a csv file into Azure app settings (web staging) using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, azure, azure-web-app-service

This is the code I am using. It works fine on live slots but not on staging slots.

```
$csv = "C:\WorkDir\web-app-settings.csv"
$appSettingsList = Import-Csv $csv 
$resourcegroupname = "DevOp-Test-RG"
$name = "web-uks-staging"

$appSettingsHash = @{}
  Write-Host "current app settings" -foreground yellow;
  ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingsList) {
  $appSettingsHash[$kvp.Key] = $kvp.Value
  write-host $kvp.Key ": " $kvp.Value -foreground green;
Set-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Name $name -AppSettings $appSettingsHash
```

The error that pops up in powershell is "Set-AzureRMWebApp:The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/web-uks-staging' under resource 
group 'DevOp-Test-RG' was not found."

I would appreciate the help a lot. Many thanks.

Comment: Also I have triple checked that the staging slot name is correct just to make sure there was no typo in powershell.

Comment: Live slots do you mean web app? staging slots I think it is a deployment slot. You should use `Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot` to modify application settings.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-5.0.0) to modify an Azure Web App staging slot. Modify your script like below:

```
$csv = "d:\webapp.csv"
$appSettingsList = Import-Csv $csv 
$resourcegroupname = "shuiapp"
$appname="shuicli"
$soltname = "shuisolt"

$appSettingsHash = @{}
  Write-Host "current app settings" -foreground yellow;
  ForEach ($kvp in $appSettingsList) {
  $appSettingsHash[$kvp.Key] = $kvp.Value
  write-host $kvp.Key ": " $kvp.Value -foreground green;

Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupname -Name $appname -Slot $soltname -AppSettings $appSettingsHash

}
```